# Share url by Facebook's Sharer.php

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, facebook-graph-api, safari

I want to share url by Facebook's Sharer.php on mobile (iOS).

So here is my link which I open in Safari:

```
  http://m.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=http://go.com&t=TEST
```

After I share that, I have a redirect to:

```
 https://www.facebook.com/dialog/return/close#_=_
```

How can I change redirect url? Because of mobile - its a blank page

Comment: Suggest you use the current version of the Share dialog, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog

Comment: @CBroe it's too long to implement that. Also need to add domains for all urls

Comment: Pretty sure you can not specify your own direct URI without using your own app id.